# What happens with determinants in affine trasnformation?

Tags: matrices, geometry, simplex

I am trying to understand these notes: [A Note On The Volume Of A Simplex](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_W2mJvkcd2i74_3-c_Ha5lITGoEwL-Lm/view?usp=sharing). Here the author uses an affine transformation $X = AY + B$ where $detA \neq 0$ and $B$ is a colum vector to show that the volume of the simplex generated by the points that make up the $X$ matrix is the same as the one generated by the ones that make the $Y$ matrix.

To do that they first write this equality which I asumme stems from the affine transformation:

$$[X_2 - X_1, \dots, X_{n+1} - X_1] = A [Y_2 - Y_1, \dots, Y_{n+1} - X_1]$$

They then aply a determinant to the eqution and arrive to this conclusion:

\begin{equation}
    det \begin{bmatrix}
        X_1, \dots, X_{n+1} \\
        1, \dots, 1
    \end{bmatrix} =
    det A
    \begin{bmatrix}
        Y_1, \dots, Y_{n+1} \\
        1, \dots, 1
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

So my question is where did the $B$ go? At first I thought since its a fixed vector it could've been assumed to be the vector zero and been discarded but further on its mentionned that $A$ and $B$ are specific matrix so that $Y$'s points look like this: $Y_1 = (y_0, 0, \dots, 0)$, $Y_r = (0, y_{r2}, \dots, y_{rn})$ So now I'm not so sure the $B$ simnply vanished.

If anyone could explain this to me or/and direct me to any aditional reading that could help me understand what happenned here better I would really apreaciate it.

Comment: The key idea is that the last row of all ones in the matrix/determinant is multiplied by $B$ and added to all of the other rows.

Comment: @Somos I'm having a hard time picturing multiplying the B since its a sum but I'm assuming you meant the transformation matrix? If so it wouldn't it multiply with A first?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplex in $n$ dimensions has $n+1$ vertices. To describe its shape and orientation but not its position, you can subtract the coordinates of one vertex from all the others. That's what's happening in your equation: $X_1$ is subtracted from all the other $X_i$:

$$[X_2 - X_1, \dots, X_{n+1} - X_1] = A [Y_2 - Y_1, \dots, Y_{n+1} - Y_1]$$

Now the offset $B$ occurs on each side of each of these differences, so it cancels out.

$$X_2-X_1=(AY_2+B)-(AY_1+B)=AY_2+B-AY_1-B=
AY_2-AY_1=A(Y_2-Y_1)$$

The same happens for all the other differences.

Comment: Thankyou very much that does make it clear. Do you know where I could read some more in affine transformations so I could understand/find who exactly are A and B for this case?